# SSIS: How to reference input columns in a Component Script?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I need to reference a column in a component script to add it's value to a string builder.  From there i need to send the string builder to an output column.

thanks

Comment: I need to do something like dtssource("Loc").tostring

Answer (score 1):

On the Script Component Editor on the Input columns tab, check off the column that you need.  That will add two properties to your input buffer (usually called row unless you changed it): yourvariable and yourvariable_isnull.  The value you need is in row.yourvariable.